# Save Geolocation in php variables

Tags: php, html, variables, geolocation

i want to save the latitude & longitude into php variables
For example i want a output like this:

```
<?php echo $latitude ?>
```

Here's the script for capturing the location(from w3schools)

```
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
}
</script>
```

But i really dont know how to save the coords inside this funktion :/

Comment: That geo code is in javascript, so you won't be able to access any of those variables in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript executes in browser after the PHP execution completes in server, so you will never be able to use JavaScript variable inside PHP.

However if you intend to save geolocation somewhere you can make an ajax call after geocoder executes to save location latitude and longitude to your database by user id or any parameter you are capturing.

```
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
    $.ajax({
        // you ajax code here
    });
}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, if you find answer to be resolving your question, you can accept the answer by green checkmark